# Date ISO 8601 in URL

Tags: php, url, timestamp, iso8601

We are receiving a ISO 8601 date in a URL from another source that looks like this:

```
echo $_GET['timestamp'];
result: 2014-11-12T12:20:00.635
```

Their documentation reads that the format should be YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssTZD

Example: 2014-11-12T12:20:00+01:00

How come our result ends with .635? What does it mean? Or are we interpreting the GET from the URL wrong?

Comment: Tested it again and now we are receiving: 2014-11-13T12:10:03.132 so it doesn't look like it's a timezone indication?

Answer (score 0):

We found out that te last numbers in the timestamp are milliseconds. This solves our question but not our initial problem. The timestamp is used to create a sha token but it seems we are missing the timezone.